# How to change visibility of layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout, visibility

There is a way to change the visibility of View in the XML, but how can I change programmatically visibility of the layout defined in XML? How to get the layout object?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/contacts_type"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Have a look at `View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE)`.

From the [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29):

> `public void setVisibility(int visibility)`
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> *Set the enabled state of this view.*
>       Related XML Attributes: android:visibility
>
> **Parameters:**
>       `visibility`     One of VISIBLE, INVISIBLE, or GONE.

Note that [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) is a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) which in turn is a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). That is, you may very well call, for instance, `myLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

This makes sense. If you have any experience with AWT/Swing, you'll recognize it from the relation between `Container` and `Component`. (A `Container` *is a* `Component`.)

Comment: I'm asking about LAYOUT not VIEW.

Comment: LinearLayout inherits from a View so this should work http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Answer (score 14):

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
view.setText("Add your text here");
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this Layout in your xml file

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/contacts_type"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="gone">
</LinearLayout>
```

Define your layout in .class file

```
 LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts_type);
```

Now if you want to display this layout just write

```
 linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and if you want to hide layout just write

```
 linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change layout visibility just in the same way as for regular view. 
Use setVisibility(View.GONE) etc. All layouts are just Views, they have View as their parent.

Answer (score 2):

this is a programatical approach:

```
 view.setVisibility(View.GONE); //For GONE
 view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //For INVISIBLE
 view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //For VISIBLE
```