# Why layout does not become invisible?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-studio

So my layout is still visible, maybe someone sees mistake? I want to dispear it when infoButton(imagebutton) is clicked.

```
FrameLayout infolayout;
infolayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoLayout);
public void infoPressed(View v){//info button is pressed by user
        //infoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

        infolayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/serviceLayout"
    android:id="@+id/infoLayout">
```

I wacthed: [How to change visibility of layout programaticly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465841/how-to-change-visibility-of-layout-programaticly)

EDITED: 
wrong code part, still not working for me

Comment: Maybe id is `serviceLayout` not `R.id.infoLayout`?

Comment: Where  are  you adding listener to your button??

Comment: '<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:id="@+id/infobutton1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:src="@mipmap/infobutton1"
            android:onClick="infoPressed"
            android:visibility="visible" />'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if your ID declaration is correct I guess you have to change the line

```
infolayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

to

```
infolayout.setVisibility(FrameLayout.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try this**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.demo.MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/serviceLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHide"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:onClick="infoPressed"
    android:text="Hide" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    FrameLayout infolayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        infolayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.serviceLayout);
    }

    public void infoPressed(View v){ //info button is pressed by user
    //infoLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); 

        infolayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}
```

Comment: there is no difference with mine code , same s**t i have too :/

Comment: you used infoLayout  instead of serviceLayout plz check your code

Comment: I changed it... watch again

Comment: FOUND MISTAKE : 
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="385dp"
    android:layout_height="525dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitEnd"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    >

this is bad, how to fix it?

Comment: xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; android:layout_width="385dp" android:layout_height="525dp"